# react-navigation for react-native: Where is the SwitchNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Today, I updated my code to the latest version of react-navigation and now receiving the following `error` :

> error: bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MyUser/WebstormProjects/project1/node_modules/react-navigation/src/navigators/SwitchNavigator.js'

If I go to this folder, sure enough the file is not there.  I have been trying to find a link to information regarding when the `SwitchNavigator` was removed so I can go back to the latest version that contained it, so I could downgrade?  Also, if there is a new alternative, I would like information on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent version , you should be importing createSwitchNavigator rather than SwitchNavigator. Please checkout https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/04/06/react-navigation-2.0-rc.html